# How can I use Beautiful Soup to webscrape also the URLs to be used in my pandas dataframe

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-mining

I am attempting to webscrape the following URL: http://eecs.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/programmes

I have the following code:

```
#Create loop to look for the td tag and print the rows
for row in rows:
   row_td = row.find_all('td')
   row_url = row.find_all('a')  
   print(row_td)
 type(row_td)
```

This produces the following result:

```
[<td>Artificial Intelligence</td>, <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/coursefinder/courses/artificial-intelligence-msc/" title="Use alt + click to follow the link">I4U2</a> </td>, <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/coursefinder/courses/artificial-intelligence-msc/" title="Use alt + click to follow the link">I4U1</a> </td>]
[<td>Artificial Intelligence with Machine Learning (January 2022 Entry Only)</td>, <td style="text-align: center;"> </td>, <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/coursefinder/courses/artificial-intelligence-with-machine-learning-msc/">I4U8</a></td>]
[<td><span>Big Data Science</span></td>, <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/coursefinder/courses/big-data-science-msc/">H6J6</a></td>, <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/coursefinder/courses/big-data-science-msc/">H6J7</a></td>]
[<td><span>Big Data Science with Machine Learning Systems (January 2022 Entry Only)</span></td>, <td style="text-align: center;"> </td>, <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/coursefinder/courses/big-data-science-with-machine-learning-systems-msc/">I4U7</a></td>]
```

As you can see, for each there is a title of the course, a URL and code for full time and then a URL and code for part time on the subsequent line. I would like to record these so it would read:

Artificial Intelligence, https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/coursefinder/courses/artificial-intelligence-msc, I4U2, https://www.qmul.ac.uk/postgraduate/taught/coursefinder/courses/artificial-intelligence-msc/, I4U1.

I have used the following code to clean up the rows so that I can achieve this, however, it isn't including the URL's.

```
INPUT:
str_cells = str(row_td)
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(str_cells).get_text()
print(cleantext)

OUTPUT: 
[Digital and Technology Solutions (Apprenticeship), I4DA,  ]
```

Would you be able to assist so that I can include the URLs in the output as well please?

I have found out that I can select the URLs using **soup.find_all("a")** but I cannot work out how to combine this with the code above.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I have amended my code, using the suggestion below, however, when I am attempting to add this as a pandas dataframe it does not seem to be working correctly. Would someone be able to spot my mistake please, and help me to convert this to a pandas dataframe?

```
dfObj = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'])
for row in rows:
   courses = row.find_all("td")
# The fragments list will store things to be included in the final 
   string, such as the course title and its URLs
   fragments = []
   for course in courses:
      if course.text.isspace():
        continue
     # Add the <td>'s text to fragments
     fragments.append(course.text)
      # Try and find an <a> tag 
     a_tag = course.find("a")
     if a_tag:
        # If one was found, add the URL to fragments
        fragments.append(a_tag["href"])

     # Make a string containing every fragment with ", " spacing them apart.
         cleantext = ", ".join(fragments)
         series_obj = pd.Series(cleantext, 
                    index=dfObj.columns)
          # Add a series as a row to the dataframe  
         mod_df = dfObj.append(  series_obj,
                     ignore_index=True) 

  print(mod_df)
```

I then get the following ouput:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can build the string by taking advantage of the `.text` property of BeautifulSoup4's `Tag` objects, and storing things in an intermediate variable (I chose a list so that combining the items with a comma is easier).

Here's a fully-fledged example:

```py
for row in rows:
    children = row.find_all("td")
    # The fragments list will store all of the stuff we want
    # included in the final string, such as the course title and
    # its URLs.
    fragments = []
    for child in children:
        # Ignore <td> tags without text (can happen when no
        # part-time version of a course exists)
        if child.text.isspace():
            continue
        # Add the <td>'s text to fragments. This could be the course
        # title (e.g. Internet of Things (Data)) or its ID (e.g. I1T2)
        fragments.append(child.text)
        # Try and find an <a> tag in the child <td>.
        a_tag = child.find("a")
        if a_tag:
            # If one was found, add the URL to fragments.
            fragments.append(a_tag["href"])

    # Make a string containing every fragment with ", " spacing them apart.
    cleantext = ", ".join(fragments)
    print(cleantext)
```

Comment: If you want the link to go before the course's ID, just move `fragments.append(child.text)` to be after the `if a_tag` block.